# How to view thumbnail of all types(jpg,png,bmp,etc.,) of attachment images in android chat application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-developer-api

In android chat development while attaching files in chat messages (like attaching file in social chat apps) I can see only the thumbnail of png attached images only in chatting page. I cannot see other image format such as jpg,bitmap (thumbnails) instead those images appear as small file icon with image name overlapped. Help me out how to fix.

This is format I tried equalsIgnoreCase("image/png"). Here I tried changing jpg,bmp but not getting the image in chat page.And i am using universal image loader